# "System.Xml.XmlAttribute cannot be used as: 'xml element'." while running my asmx service

Tags: asp.net, asmx

I am trying to create a small asmx service with a method which will return some dummy data. I get the following error when I run the service:
"System.InvalidOperationException: System.Xml.XmlAttribute cannot be used as: 'xml element'."

My web method is as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public SubmitCaseRequestResponse1 SubmitCaseRequest(SubmitCaseRequestRequest1 request)
{

    var response = new SubmitCaseRequestResponse1
    {
        ResponseID = "456325898",
        Success = true,
        ValidationErrors = null

    };
    return response;
}
```

My SubmitCaseRequestResponse1  class:

```
public class SubmitCaseRequestResponse1
```

{
    public string ResponseId { get; set; }

```
public bool Success { get; set; }

public ValidationError[] ValidationErrors { get; set; }
```

}

and the request class is :

```
public class SubmitCaseRequestRequest1
```

{
    public AuthHeader AuthHeader { get; set; }

```
public SubmitCaseRequestRequest PostCaseDateRequest { get; set; }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was supposed to serialize the complex type SubmitCaseRequestRequest1   and SubmitCaseRequestResponse1 . Needed to add [XmlElement] for the complex types and [XmlAttribute] for simple types

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[Serializable]
public class SubmitCaseRequestRequest1
{
    [XmlElement]
    public AuthHeader AuthHeader { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public SubmitCaseRequestRequest PostCaseDateRequest { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class SubmitCaseRequestRequest
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Guid? RequestId { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string LCICourtNumber { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string DebtorLastName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string DateType { get; set; }
}
```